Remote melacha: remoting into a place where it is Shabbat or Yom Tov

VR control of robots in other locations is a thing. In fact, there is a concept of actually working this way. This article* describes a robot that can be manually controlled to stack shelves, and people can remote into it to do the work from home. They see through its cameras in VR, and they control its arms, and move it around, with hand-held controllers.
See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxWH5XAcFnM
In theory, the person can control a robot anywhere in the world.
What is the halacha of performing this work for a company that is in a timezone where it is currently Shabbat for them but not you? Is this the same question as all timezone/melacha questions, or is there something novel here, because of the control of the robot, which physically moves under said control?
For review:
If it's fine, and identical to other "remote melacha timezone" questions, then, even though it might be halachically identical on the surface, perhaps there are other considerations. For example, if this became widespread, cheap, and common, people might start remoting in to visit their family on Shabbat (note: I don't want to get into the halacha of CCTV, babycams etc). They might start doing melachot for them (with or without being asked).
So, it might be a "spirit of the law" thing, or a posek might forbid it due to potential misuses like this etc.
* The pictures in this article are fine, but I have ad blocker so I can't verify if the ad service they use is kosher. Click at your own risk!

The dupe question is a significantly different scenario. Imagine we could take VR control over a robot in a country where it is shabbat, and use it to light a fire, dig a hole, etc. That may indeed be a halachically identical situation to this (which is a better candidate for duplicate imo), but it "feels" different and therefore my question is specifically: is it different? I think that makes this question unique. What does the community think?

I used to work from the US on a computing cluster in Europe.  I also regularly met on video with colleagues in Europe (they were not Jewish).
When I started, I asked my LOR if it was ok to do these things on Friday afternoon and was told it was no problem.
